# Popover doesn't work with ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to show a popover after mouseenter on a ng-grid cell, but it failed.
What am I doing wrong?

Here's the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/pucSb6?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've forked your plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/EUhUxPHhS674E7eeTBmP

I have updated your `ui-bootstrap` version to 0.10.0:

```
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
```

And have set `popover-placement="top" popover-append-to-body="true"` in your poppedover `div`.

Comment: Can you please update your plunkr ? It isn't working

Comment: Done, have fun.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Why have u used `ng-grid.debug.js` ?

Comment: I have installed `ui-grid` in my project using bower. The ng-grid installed by bower doesn't have this file. Instead only `ui-grid.js` only

Comment: oops i just realized that you have used `ng-grid`. I was actually looking for `ui-grid`.