# Popover in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, popover, ng-grid

I am trying to use Popover in my project and I am referring this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836381/popover-doesnt-work-with-ng-grid/25671869#25671869) :

```
var templatePopover = '<div popover={{row.entity.name}} popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-placement="top" popover-append-to-body="true">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>';
```

What is {{row.getProperty(col.field)}} for? Where is col.field in the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set your column definitions for ng-grid, you tell it the name of the field.

```
gridOptions: {  
columnDefs: [
      {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name', cellTemplate: templatePopover},
      {field: 'age',  displayName: 'Age'}
]
}
```

So when you reference

```
{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}
```

You are saying get the value for the current row, for that field. In this case, get the current row's 'name' field, since that is the column that you have placed templatePopover on.

Edit: 
Here is an update of your plunker with 2 changes: First: disable the flexible height plugin otherwise nothing showed up at all in the grid - probably this plunker just doesn't have that and it didn't seem relevant to your question. Second: turn on row selection and you get the hand icon back. I don't know what you mean about taking out the col.field part and still seeing the data. The plunker you gave me still had it in there.
http://plnkr.co/edit/TVWsmEGXUDgNhlLrkWXY?p=preview

Comment: Okay. I saw in that plunker that if I remove that col.field, I can not see the data there but in my case, although I remove it, I can still see the data in ng-grid. Also, I observed that when I mouseover the data, it becomes "hand-tool" in plunker. In my case, it is still pointer. In my project, I have many gridoptions there other than columnDefs. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please provide a plunker that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Thanks Imyers. Your edited plunker worked for me. God bless you. :)

Comment: Fixed. ng-grid source code was moved. If this answer helped you, please consider up-voting. Thanks.

Comment: @imyers: The plunkr is not working again. Can we enable popover only for some columns ?